# How to parse with column from excel to convert it to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, js-xlsx, sheetjs

I have tried to display the json value from the table.

But it creates the JSON from Excel (Which parse as an row)

I would like to parse the excel data as an column wise.

Please help on this.

I am using angular to parse.

```
 Upload() {
     console.log(XLSX)
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (e) => {
            this.arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
            var data = new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer);
            var arr = new Array();
            for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
            var bstr = arr.join("");
            var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});
            var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[1];
            var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
            console.log(worksheet)
            console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true,sheetRows: 0}));
        }
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
}
```

```html
         <table>
         <tr>
         <td>
         NodeID
         </td>
         <td>
         Coles
         </td>
         <td>
         Platinum
         </td>
         <td>
         Rewards
         </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>
         test
         </td>
         <td>
         15
         </td>
         <td>
         14
         </td>
         <td>
         12
         </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>
         Test2
         </td>
         <td>
         56
         </td>
         <td>
         5656
         </td>
         <td>
         12
         </td>
         </tr>
         </table>
```

I referred the below link, but no use.
https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/691

The above excel should be parse from column wise as JSON

The output should be

{NodeId   : {test1: 15,Test2:56}}

Comment: Did you find anything? I'm stuck in the same boat as you were.

Comment: I have used js-xlsx package

Answer (score 0):

You could use this package from NPM to make your life alot easier:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson

also note that its better to use const/let (not: var) and forEach() instead of for()

Comment: I used js-xlsx from npm packagae to convert excel file to JSON 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-xlsx

Comment: https://github.com/Robbie106gti/nc-catalog/blob/master/src/sop/components/csvtojson/csvtojson.component.ts